# How can I pass a long javascript string to PHP hook_menu in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, routes

On mysite/build-order I have a long order code that I'm assembling using Javacsript and sending via _GET in the URL to a hook_menu page for processing.

It can be as long as this (or longer), and am sending it to the create-order page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //...building code
    var orderCode = "sku:OR-4x4>qty:2>prc:55.00>nfo:OR-4x4,sku:CVR>qty:1>prc:50>nfo:OR-4x4,sku:PF>qty:15>prc:2>nfo:OR-4x4 (sdfsdfg),sku:EM>qty:2>prc:12.95>nfo:OR-4x4 (sdfsdfg),sku:SC>prc:25>qty:4>nfo:Some description,sku:DB>qty:10>prc:4>nfo:Some description,sku:ES>qty:10>prc:3>nfo:BlahBlah,sku:OR-4x4>qty:2>prc:55.00>nfo:OR-4x4,sku:CVR>qty:1>prc:50>nfo:OR-4x4,sku:PF>qty:15>prc:2>nfo:OR-4x4 (sdfsdfg),sku:EM>qty:2>prc:12.95>nfo:OR-4x4 (sdfsdfg),sku:SC>prc:25>qty:4>nfo:Some description,sku:DB>qty:10>prc:4>nfo:BlahBlah-visiondelimiter-Phasellus laoreet lorem vel dolor tempus vehicula. Curabitur blandit tempus ardua ridiculus sed magna. Quisque placerat facilisis egestas cillum dolore.-visiondelimiter-eventName";

    var url = '/create-order/' + orderCode;
    window.location.replace(url);
</script>
```

Ive implemented a hook_menu setup in my custom module called "create_order_menu" and it works fine.

```
function mymodule_create_order_menu($ordercode){

    // do stuff with $ordercode

}
```

It all works fine. The only problem is that the order code string passed through the URL can sometimes be twice as long and it trips a 404 Error in the mysite/create-order page. When I shorten the code, it works. When I lengthen it again, it breaks.

Is there a better way to send such a lengthy variable to my hook_menu page setup?

Comment: method GET seems to be the problem, check this http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you consider some pretty substantial changes to how you're doing things.

I would recommend using an AJAX request, probably with POST rather than GET,  and don't try to do the redirect.   Just update the interface with a "success" message for the user.